# CMake multiline message with FATAL_ERROR

Tags: cmake

CMake documentation (for example current [version 3.11.2](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/message.html)) states

> CMake Warning and Error message text displays using a simple markup language. Non-indented text is formatted in line-wrapped paragraphs delimited by newlines. Indented text is considered pre-formatted.

However, it doesn't mention any markup format. Unless the "non-indented" vs. "indented" is all there is about the "simple markup".

Anyway, I failed to make it work with `FATAL_ERROR` mode.

Furthermore, I noticed that with `STATUS` mode message is printed with leading `--` (two dashes and space). While with `FATAL_ERROR` every line break in the message is turned into two lines, which (IMHO) looks awful.

Now I have a multiline message which lists what is wrong in `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and what values are accepted. Because of above-mentioned issues, I ended up printing the message as `STATUS` and indenting subsequent lines with three spaces (so they align well with the `--`). Then I do a simple `FATAL_ERROR` repeating only the "title line" (stating that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is wrong). This looks acceptable on both console output and `cmake-gui`. (Although the 3 spaces indentation is needless on `cmake-gui`...)

However, I'm surprised how poorly is this topic described. And it seems to be so since long - see for example question [[CMake] Extra blank lines with SEND_ERROR and FATAL_ERROR ?!](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-October/032448.html) remaining unanswered for almost 9 years now...

Are there any good practices, advice or tips for handling such messages? Or should they be avoided in the first place?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're right. The "simple markup" is either non-indented (unformatted) or indented (formatted). Also, the non-indented text is in *paragraphs* delimited by newlines. That's why you end up with blank lines in between paragraphs.

Here's a running explanation of the various kinds of messages. Warning types and error types behave the same as far as formatted vs. unformatted text goes. The difference, of course, is what happens to the processing and generation phases of CMake. For readability, you can split strings into multiple double-quoted pieces that will be concatenated.

```
# STATUS
message(STATUS
    "This is a status message. It is prefixed with \"-- \". It goes to stdout. The "
    "lines will wrap according to the width of your terminal.\n"
    "New lines will begin a new line at column 1, but without the \"-- \" prefix, "
    "unless you provide it; they will not create a blank line (i.e., new "
    "paragraph).   Spacing between sentences is unaltered by CMake.\n"
    "-- Here's a new paragraph with an explicit \"-- \" prefix added.")

# no mode given (informational)
message(
    "This is an informational message. It goes to stderr. Each line begins at column "
    "1. The lines will wrap according to the width of your terminal.\n"
    "New lines will begin a new line at column 1; they will not create a blank line "
    "(i.e., new paragraph).   Spacing between sentences is unaltered by CMake (3 spaces "
    "preceded this sentence.).")

# WARNING--unformatted
message(WARNING
    "This is an unformatted warning message.   It goes to stderr. Each line begins "
    "at column 3. The lines will wrap at a particular column (it appears to be "
    "column 77, set within CMake) and wrap back to column 3.\n"
    "New lines will begin a new paragraph, so they will create a blank line. A final "
    "thing about unformatted messages: They will separate sentences with 2 spaces, "
    "even if your string had something  different.")

# WARNING--formatted and unformatted
message(WARNING
    " This is a formatted warning message. It goes to stderr. Formatted lines will"
    " be indented an additional 2 spaces beyond what was provided in the output"
    " string. The lines will wrap according to the width of your terminal.\n"
    " Indented new lines will begin a new line. They will not create a blank line."
    " If you separate sentences with 1 space, that's what you'll get.  If you"
    " separate them with 2 spaces, that's also what you'll get.\n"
    " If you want to control the width of the formatted paragraphs\n"
    " (a good practice), just keep track of the width of each line and place\n"
    " a \"\\n\" at the end of each line.\n \n"
    " And, if you want a blank line between paragraphs, just place \"\\n \\n\"\n"
    " (i.e., 2 newlines separated by a space) at the end of the first paragraph.\n"
    "Non-indented new lines, however, will be treated like unformatted warning "
    "messages, described above. They will begin at and wrap to column 3. They begin "
    "a new paragraph, so they will create a blank line.    There will be 2 spaces "
    "between sentences, regardless of how many you placed after the period (In the "
    "script, there were 4 spaces before this sentence).\n"
    "And, as you'd expect, a second unindented paragraph will be preceded by a "
    "blank line. But why would you mix formatted and unformatted text?")
```

I saved this into Message.cmake and invoked it with `cmake -P Message.cmake 2> output.txt`. It results in the following stdout:

```
-- This is a status message. It is prefixed with "-- ". It goes to stdout. The lines will wrap according to the width of your terminal.
New lines will begin a new line at column 1, but without the "-- " prefix, unless you provide it; they will not create a blank line (i.e., new paragraph).   Spacing between sentences is unaltered by CMake.
-- Here's a new paragraph with an explicit "-- " prefix added.
```

The file, output.txt, contains:

```
This is an informational message. It goes to stderr. Each line begins at column 1. The lines will wrap according to the width of your terminal.
New lines will begin a new line at column 1; they will not create a blank line (i.e., new paragraph).   Spacing between sentences is unaltered by CMake (3 spaces preceded this sentence.).
CMake Warning at MessageScript.cmake:19 (message):
  This is an unformatted warning message.  It goes to stderr.  Each line
  begins at column 3.  The lines will wrap at a particular column (it appears
  to be column 77, set within CMake) and wrap back to column 3.

  New lines will begin a new paragraph, so they will create a blank line.  A
  final thing about unformatted messages: They will separate sentences with 2
  spaces, even if your string had something different.


CMake Warning at MessageScript.cmake:28 (message):
   This is a formatted warning message. It goes to stderr. Formatted lines will be indented an additional 2 spaces beyond what was provided in the output string. The lines will wrap according to the width of your terminal.
   Indented new lines will begin a new line. They will not create a blank line. If you separate sentences with 1 space, that's what you'll get.  If you separate them with 2 spaces, that's also what you'll get.
   If you want to control the width of the formatted paragraphs
   (a good practice), just keep track of the width of each line and place
   a "\n" at the end of each line.

   And, if you want a blank line between paragraphs, just place "\n \n"
   (i.e., 2 newlines separated by a space) at the end of the first paragraph.

  Non-indented new lines, however, will be treated like unformatted warning
  messages, described above.  They will begin at and wrap to column 3.  They
  begin a new paragraph, so they will create a blank line.  There will be 2
  spaces between sentences, regardless of how many you placed after the
  period (In the script, there were 4 spaces before this sentence).

  And, as you'd expect, a second unindented paragraph will be preceded by a
  blank line.  But why would you mix formatted and unformatted text?
```

**SUMMARY**

*INFORMATIONAL MESSAGES (no mode given)*

- start at column 1
- wrap in terminal window until newline
- go to stderr
- new paragraphs begin without preceding blank line
- sentence and word spacing preserved

*STATUS MESSAGES*

- start at column 1, with "-- " prefix on first paragraph
- wrap in terminal window until newline
- go to stdout
- new paragraphs begin without preceding blank line
- sentence and word spacing preserved

*UNFORMATTED WARNING AND ERROR MESSAGES (unindented strings)*

- start at column 3
- wrap at column 77
- go to stderr
- new paragraphs are preceded by a blank line
- sentences separated by 2 spaces; words by 1 space

*FORMATTED WARNING AND ERROR MESSAGES (indented strings)*

- start at column 3, plus whatever indentation the string had
- wrap in terminal window until newline
- go to stderr
- new paragraphs begin without preceding blank line
- sentence and word spacing preserved